# What's the real procedure of evaluating recursive data in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to understand recursive data, and I'm a little confused. I tried this:

```
m = 1 : map (+1) m
```

and this produced a list identical to `[1..]`. I tried to complete the evaluation procedure like this:

```
m = 1 : map (+1) m
  = 1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) m)
  = 1 : 2 : map (+1) (map (+1) m)
  = 1 : 2 : map (+1) (map (+1) (1 : 2 : map (+1) (map (+1) m)) )
  = 1 : 2 : map (+1) (2 : map (+1) (2 : (map (+1) (map (+1) m)) )
  = 1 : 2 : 3 : map (+1) (map (+1) (2 : (map (+1) (map (+1) m)))
  = 1 : 2 : 3 : map (+1) (3 : map (+1) ( (map (+1) (map (+1) m))) )
  = 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : map (+1) (map (+1) ( (map (+1) (map (+1) m)) ))
  = ...
```

there are a lot of `map (+1)` stuff in the tail and increasing with the procedure. Are there really so many `map (+1)` and repeated calculation of `map (+1) ...` ? I've read other posts mentioning thunks, but how to actually relate them all together? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would happen is more like the following

```
m = 1 : map (+1) m
    1 : map (+1) (1 : _)
        ^------------<|     Points to the same thunk in memory
    1 : a : map (+1) (a : _) where a = ((+1) 1)
            ^------------<|
    1 : 2 : map (+1) (2 : _)
            ^------------<|
    1 : 2 : a : map (+1) (a : _) where a = ((+1) 2)
                ^------------<|
    1 : 2 : 3 : map (+1) (3 : _)
                ^------------<|
    1 : 2 : 3 : a : map (+1) (a : _) where a = ((+1) 3)
                    ^------------<|
    1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : map (+1) (4 : _)
                    ^------------<|
```

The next element in the list passed to `map` always points back to the element `map` is about to generate.

However, it is important to note that the Haskell specification states that it must be lazy, but the manner in which the laziness is implemented is up to the compiler.  It may choose to optimize away a lot of this into a simple loop in assembly, or depending on how the output is used, it might do some loop fusion to combine several traversals into one.

Comment: thank you for you answer. Does it mean, that the "map (+1) (1 : _)" itself in the 2nd becomes the thunk, and the thunk of 2nd becomes "a : map (+1) ..." in the 3rd? but i don't quite understand what makes each thunk strictly keep pointing to the map in the same level of recursion. It looks like a pattern matching in the scope of the previous thunk, I think.

Comment: @fangyc Yes, the `map (+1) (...)` keeps becoming the next thunk each time it produces a new element.  Another way to think of it is as an [iterator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) from object oriented languages.  It operates in much the same way, but is the default behavior in Haskell and works with all types (except specifically strict types).

Comment: @fangyc You might be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140177/observing-lazyness-in-haskell) post from earlier today, someone else had a very similar question to yours and the answer given shows how you can actually view this evaluation, and lucky for me it agrees with the answer I've given.  It might help you understand it a bit more.

Comment: I'm trying that tool with the help of the info you provided. It is great and I've understood more. Thank you.